# how to add view in AppBundle?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to experiment in symfony3. I'm trying to search it to google but I found no clear answer from them. This is the default controller in symfony

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        // replace this example code with whatever you need
        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', [
            'base_dir' => realpath($this->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/..').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
        ]);
    }
}
```

If you see the return render. It will display the **default/index.html.twig** from the **app/Resources/views/default/index.html.twig** I would like to know if this possible to put my view folder in my AppBundle folder? here is my list folder in AppBundle

```
AppBundle
 -Controller
 -Entity
 -Form
 -Resources
    -views
      -default
        -index.html.twig
```

How can I link it to the resources under my AppBundle? If you have tutorial please give link. thanks in advance

Comment: What you posted looks like it should work.  Try clearing the cache and make sure you have removed the app/Resources file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Symfony2 started with views under the AppBundle/Resources, and Symfony3 try to encourage you to separate the frontend (html/js/css)  from your Business php Bundle by placing them in `app/Resources`.

Anyway if you want to structure the code as you describe it (like symfony2 standard), the syntax to use is `bundle:folder:subdirs/views.html.twig`

```
AppBundle // first parameter
 -Controller
 -Entity
 -Form
 -Resources
    -views
      -default //second parameter
        - index.html.twig
        - subfolder
           - _included.html.twig
           - subsubfolder
              - _very_included.html.twig
```

In this example:

- `index.html.twig` the syntax will be `AppBundle:default:index.html.twig`
- `_included.html.twig` the syntax will be `AppBundle:default:subfolder/_included.html.twig`
- `_very_included.html.twig` the syntax will be `AppBundle:default:subfolder/subsubfolder/_very_included.html.twig`

For your concrete problem it will be `AppBundle:default:index.html.twig`

Comment: "Symfony3 try to encourage you to separate the frontend (html/js/css) from your Business php Bundle". If that's the case, then why does assetic load assets from @AppBundle?

Comment: It encourage you, you are not forced to do it. Symfony 3 best practice is to put them in app/Resources, not src/Appbundle/Resources.

Comment: What if you have multiple subfolders? if file is in `../views/default/sub1/sub2/sub3/tmpl.html.twig` is it `AppBundle:default:sub1:sub2:sub3/tmpl.html.twig` or `AppBundle:default:sub1/sub2/sub3/tmpl.html.twig` ? if the latter, why the arbitrary number of colons `:` are converted into slashes `/` ?